# Mists of Pandaria ambiguous and aggressive tonality

Tags: theory, analysis

I've been trying to analyze [Heart of Pandaria](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsDRarTOtas) by Russel Brower which is a World of Warcraft song, And I'm having problem decoding what chords are being used to create a surprise and aggression in 00:17. if you know any information about these kind of movements (any harmonic rule or suggestion) please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like a [chromatic mediant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_mediant) relationship, with a melody note on the top of the chord that "escapes" at 0:17 to create an effect of surprise.  the chromatic mediant relationship is used a lot in film scores, I suppose because it is still a somewhat surprising shift in tonality.

Answer (score 1):

Chandrew is most of the way there; it is a chromatic mediant relationship.

The opening chord is F minor; the chord at 00:17 is Af minor. In F minor, this Af chord would usually be *major* (Af--C--Ef), but here the composer uses a Cf (with some crunchy non-chord tones in there) to surprise the listener and make it *minor*, creating a particular mood for the piece.

In terms of Roman numerals, this would be a motion from `i--iii`. Again, this is a little out of the ordinary because it would normally be `i--III`.